# how to iterate in pandas dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas

i need do some operations with my dataframe

my dataframe is

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1':[1,2],'col2':[3,4]})

    col1    col2
0      1       3
1      2       4
```

my operatin is column dependent

for example, i need to add (`+`) `.max()` of column to each value in this column

so `df.col1.max()` is `2` and `df.col2.max()` is 4

so my output should be:

```
    col1    col2
0      3       7
1      4       8
```

i have been try this:

```
for i in df.columns:
    df.i += df.i.max()
```

but

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'i'
```

Answer (score 3):

you can chain `df.add` and `df.max` and specify the axis which avoids any loops.

```
df1 = df.add(df.max(axis=0))

print(df1)

  col1  col2
0     3     7
1     4     8
```

Answer (score 1):

To loop through the columns and add the maximum of each column you can do the following:

```
for col in df:
    df[col] += df[col].max()
```

This gives

```
   col1  col2
0     3     7
1     4     8
```